# PHP showing page 500 instead of errors

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have errors in PHP but it's showing the page 500 error instead of the errors.

I tried to change the PHP.ini and htaccess also. I have this values in php.ini:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 64M;
max_execution_time = 18000;
upload_max_filesize = 999M;
safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.use_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 12000000;
allow_url_fopen = on;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
log_errors = On;
```

in htaccess I also have:

```
# Displaying PHP errors
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 6143
```

But I can't figure out how to display the errors or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: try restart your apache

Comment: check your Apache error.log

Comment: I see `ini_set()` out there. You can't normally write PHP code in your `php.ini` file: it's a static preferences file, not a script.

Comment: How do I restart my apache if this is on a online website?
If it was local, I would know how to do it.

Comment: @user2902515 You will need to gain access to the server.

Comment: Ok guys. I know that I'm on the right point to fix this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What is  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);` doing in your php.ini ?
It should be:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

Comment: Didn't work. Probably because I need to restart the server or something..but this is an online website.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up your (maybe get default one, just for test) .htaccess and php.ini file, it looks like you did some syntax errors in php.ini file..

Also depend on your dev env it is good practice to constantly monitor logs. on unix that will be

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/www_my_dev_site_acces.log
tail -f /var/log/httpd/www_my_dev_site_error.log
```